# How do we enable tty on devcontainer exec

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I want to open a shell on a dev container built on `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.6-bullseye` image

I want to open a bash shell and run commands using devcontainer exec "/bin/bash".
However, once the shell opens and when I type any command like `ls` it gets stuck.

In `docker exec` I use a `-t` argument to solve this.
How do I do this with a devcontainer